# How to reduce/close the gap between two columns in Python Dash Bootstrap

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm working with Dash Bootstrap grid layout system and I'm trying to close/reduce the gap between columns. Is there any way how to do that? Thank you. Sample code:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
row = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col
                (html.Div(dcc.Dropdown
                        (
                        id='dropdown',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'Option 1', 'value': '1'},
                            {'label': 'Option 2', 'value': '2'},
                            {'label': 'Option 3', 'value': '3'}
                        ],
                        value='1', style={'padding': '15px', 'width': '80%'}
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                dbc.Col
                (html.Div(dcc.Dropdown
                        (
                        id='dropdown-2',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'Option 4', 'value': '4'},
                            {'label': 'Option 5', 'value': '5'},
                            {'label': 'Option 6', 'value': '6'}
                        ],
                        value='4', style={'padding': '15px', 'width': '80%'}
                        ),))
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
app.layout = html.Div([row])
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(port='8085',debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers state that
`no_gutter = True`
should be used. This got depreciated and will create an 'unexpected keyword' error in newer versions.

Use className="g-0" instead ([dbc docs](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/)):

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

row = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
        dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
        dbc.Col(html.Div("One of three columns")),
    ],
    className="g-0",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the argument `no_gutters=True` to `dbc.Row` to remove them completely.

If you wanted to just reduce them you could make your own Bootstrap stylesheet and adjust the gaps to something you prefer. [This app](https://bootstrap.build/app) makes that process pretty easy, you just want to adjust the `grid-gutter-width` variable, then you can download the stylesheet and include it in your app.

Answer (score 1):

If you're alright with imprecise solutions, setting `form=True` on the `dbc.Row` object will tighten the gutters up.

For more fine-grained control, set `no_gutters=True` as was recommended in the other answer, and on the `dbc.Col` objects add `style={'margin-right': '5px', 'margin-left': '5px'}`. You can adjust those as appropriate. For end columns, you may want to remove the margin on the end.

Answer (score -1):

Set the class Name of the row to className='g-0'

Comment: This just repeats the [answer of horseshoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70495385/5459839).